# Is port 9000 allowed in Microsoft hosted ubuntu agent in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, localhost

I have sonarqube configured in my localhost with 9000 port http://www.localhost:9000/
Now, I have created a service connection in azure DevOps with this url.
when I tried to analyze a project via pipeline building on a Microsoft hosted ubuntu image.. it throws error as error connection refused for port 9000 during prepare sonaranalysis task.

error:

> ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ENOTFOUND","errno":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"www.localhost","host":"www.localhost","port":"9000"}
> Finishing: SonarQubePrepare

Could someone help to fix this?

Comment: I dont think you want to connect to localhost... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check below answer. You might need to build your local hosted agent to connect to your local sonar server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sonarqube configured in your local machine. Cloud hosted agents will not be able to access to the local hosted sonarqube server, for your local machine cannot be accessed from Microsoft cloud hosted agents.

You will need to create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) on your local machine. And run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent by targeting your private agent pool when queuing your pipeline. For the local hosted sonarqube server can be accessed from your local machine.

Another workaround is to expose your localhost:9000 to the public network using tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as 4c74356b41 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, basically this will never work, you need to have an externally available endpoint for your sonarqube and connect to that one

so something like ngrok.com might help you with that if you want to host sonarqube on your workstation